# Una consulta con suma de columna tipo REAL, arroja el resultado entre paréntesis: (00.0,)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

Cuando imprimo el resultado de una consulta con suma me aparece entre paracentesis y con una coma al final.

Lo que se imprime: (19.0,)

```py
try:
    self.cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(Cantidad) FROM TAblaVentas")
    Columa = self.cursor.fetchone()
    print (str(Columna))
except Exception as error:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El método [`fetchone()`](http://fetchone()%C2%B6) retorna una tupla como resultado, y tú estas convirtiendo la tupla a cadena de texto generando ese valor. En vez de ello debes obtener el primer elemento:

```py
try:
    self.cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(Cantidad) FROM TAblaVentas")
    resultado = self.cursor.fetchone()
    if resultado:
        suma = resultado[0]
        print(suma) 
except Exception as error:
    # ...
```