# problemas con caracteres especiales con base de datos sql server y python

Tags: python, sql-server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]tengo un problema con una aplicación en python donde al momento de hacer una consulta, toma los datos en la base de datos y lo guarda en un string pero al momento de mostrarlo se agregan caracteres especiales y no puedo corregir ese detalle..

codigo..

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};'
                  'Server=DESKTOP-ATOSSK5\LIUS24;'
                  'Database=data_SMD;'
                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''select Turno from data_SMD.dbo.General_data''')
row=cursor.fetchall()
while(row):

   turno=tk.StringVar(gral)
   turno.set('Turno')
   turnos_entry=row
   turno_entry=tk.OptionMenu(gral,turno,*turnos_entry)
   turno_entry.config(width=35,height=2)
   turno_entry.place(x=340,y=350)
   row=cursor.fetchall()
```

y al momento de mostrar los datos me lo muestra de la siguiente manera

[('1', ), ('2', ),('3', ),('4', )]

por lo cual no se si es un detalle de código o de librería pyodbc
si alguien sabe se lo agradecería mucho.
saludos y gracias

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con caracteres especiales? Lo que se muestra es simplemente la salida de fechall, una lista de tuplas en la que cada tupla contiene los datos de cada fila. El while en principio sobra.

Comment: agregue una foto de la salida que tengo en los datos... cuando se hace la consulta se agrega los paréntesis y las comillas en los datos pero no se como solucionar ese detalle

Comment: @AldoOlivas cambia a `turnos_entry=row[0]`. Relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/329737/una-consulta-con-suma-de-columna-tipo-real-arroja-el-resultado-entre-par%c3%a9ntesis/329748#329748

Comment: @eyllanesc solo muestra el primer dato del array pero este no tiene los parentesis

Comment: @AldoOlivas entonces prueba con `turnos_entry = " ".join(row)`

Comment: @eyllanesc muestra ese error:  expected str instance, pyodbc.Row found

Comment: Entonces prueba con `turnos_entry = " ".join([str(r) for r in row])`

Comment: lo imprime igual pero a cada elemento le da un salto de linea

Comment: Me parece que la columna en si no contiene lo que debería, creo que deberías comprobar que no has cometido algún error al guardar los datos en la base de datos ("('2',)",) es bastante sospechoso para empezar, parece como si hubieras guardado la representación en cadena de una tupla...

Comment: la base de datos esta correcta no hay nada anormal, el problema radica cuando se hace la consulta ya que al momento de obtener la información se agrega los paracentesis y las comillas en los datos , trate de quitar los datos con el método re.sub y el replace pero no correo el código

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCION

La mejor solucion para poder solucionar el codigo fue.

- seleccionar el dato que necesitas
- guardarlo en el array
- hacer un for dentro del array ejemplo

  copy_linea=linea.get()

  cursor.execute('''SELECT .... where ID_Lineas='''+copy_linea+ ''' ''')

  copy_modelos=[row[0]for row in cursor.fetchall()]

y para mostrarlo en el Combobox solo basta con

```
modelo_entrante["values"] =copy_modelos
```